# Asymptotically isometric copy of $\ell_1$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

A Banach space $X$ is said to contain Asymptotically isometric copy of $\ell_1$ if there is a null sequence$(\rho_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $(0,1)$  and a sequence$(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $X$ so that $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-\rho_n)|a_n|\leq\left\|\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nx_n\right\|\leq\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n|,$$ for all $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}\in\ell_1.$
I really  do not know very well this definition, especially geometry interpretation of this definition, I  would appreciate any help.

Comment: I think this definition means that $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is equivalent to unit vector basis of $\ell_1$, but I do not it is true

Comment: The same question was posted at MO, but closed: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/171843/asymptotically-isometric-copy-of-ell-1

Comment: Perhaps you should have a look at discussions about [meta-tag:cross-posting]. For example: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9337/is-cross-posted-forbidden-discouraged-on-stack-exchange-sites-if-so-why or http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting